# How to import packages inside .vue files

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, lodash

In my .vue file script area, I have this:

```
<script>
    import get from 'lodash.get';

    ...
</script>
```

I'm trying to import lodash.get, but I get `ReferenceError: get is not defined`.

In my entry file(app.js which is a normal js file) it works and I could do

```
import get from 'lodash.get';
window.get = get;
```

But it would be better to have imports in each component.

> Is there a way to import packages(lodash.get in my example) inside a
>   vue component?

My folder structure:

```
node_modules
..lodash.get
....index.js
resources
..assets
....js
......components
........ComponentWhereINeedImport.vue
....app.js
```

None of these work:

```
import { get } from 'lodash/get';
import { get } from 'lodash.get';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import get from 'lodash.get';
require('../../../../node_modules/lodash.get/index.js');
require('../../../../node_modules/lodash.get/index');
require('../../../../node_modules/lodash.get');
```

Comment: Maybe `/` instead of `.`? `lodash/get`

Comment: same error @wostex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write

```
<script>
import lodash from 'lodash';
....
```

Comment: You probably still using Import get somewhere.

Comment: I solved it now, I was using get() in another file without importing so that's where the error came from. Should have read the error msg more :) but thanks